# Spring Boot actuator health issue with Consul

Tags: consul, spring-boot-actuator

We are running consul in OpenShift cluster. All services have been developed by Spring Boot/Cloud APIs and they have been registered successfully in consul. There is a health point exposed using SpringBoot actuator. The health point itself works just fine when try to hit using curl.. sometimes we are just getting HTTP 200 status code and do not see any response. So which is causing Consul to throw below errors frequently which causes issues in discovering the service.

Any suggestions would be great help..

2016/08/05 05:57:15 [WARN] agent: http request failed 'http://10.1.0.18:9080/health': Get http://10.1.0.18:9080/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: Its been a while since this was reported but I started seeing this in my spring boot instances too. curl for health endpoint returns the actuator json response, in my case the status was DOWN due to a DB issue but couldn't figure out why consul gets the Client.timeout error. When the the DB connection was restored things were back to normal. But there is no explanation to this behavior. Also see the same error in consul ui. After the service is restored ui prints the correct json output.

Comment: Please let me know if you managed to find anything around this.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered this after a long time, my solution was increasing the timeouts for the probes, not sure if this helps after 2 years but worth a shot

Comment: Yeah, it fixes.

Comment: what property is this for the timeout?

Comment: It was definitely above 60 seconds! But I recommend do changing values and testing